# Vertical-align: bottom not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I thought vertical-align was supposed to work with inline elements.  Yet for some reason everything in the gray div is aligned to the *top*, not the bottom.

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:130px; right: 80px; width: 230px; background-color:Gray; height:30px;" class="defaultText" id="pager">
    <span style="vertical-align:bottom;">Page Size:</span>
    <select style="vertical-align:bottom; font-size:8pt; margin-top: 0; margin-left:3px; height:16px; text-align:center;">
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="10000">*</option>
    </select>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <span style="vertical-align:bottom; color:Blue; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;"><</span>
        <input style="vertical-align:bottom; height:12px; font-size:8pt; width: 20px;" type="text" data-bind="value: pageNum" />
        <span style="vertical-align:bottom;"> of </span>
        <span style="vertical-align:bottom;" data-bind="text: numPages"></span>
        <span style="vertical-align:bottom; color:Blue; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 5px;">></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with a table cell, what vertical-align does is aligns the element with respect to adjacent elements, particularly text.  So, the elements in the gray div should be lined up with *each other*, not the bottom of the div.  See examples at http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html.

Comment: Specifically, inline elements of which a div is not one of them.

Comment: vertical-align is meant for inline/text, but when it's not really about text, the "line-height" can be (ab)used in situations where no line breaks are involved, i.e. horizontally bottom-aligning a few inline-blocks.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a modern updated answer using Flex boxes.

```
div {
  height: 100%; // containing div must fill the full height of the parent div
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: For Bootstrap 4+ users it's gonna be `<div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end">CONTENT BOTTOM</div>`

Answer (score 16):

Here's an example where you can accomplish this by using the following code

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SbNKa/1/

```
#theContainer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #900;
}
.content-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 498px;
    bottom: 0; /*This is the part that glues it to the bottom*/
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
<div id="theContainer">
    <div class="content-bottom">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with the question. The question was about how to use correctly `vertical-align: bottom`

Comment: @DotNetWise: this is the answer to what the guy was trying to accomplish, not all questions are the actual question being asked. Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: You seen to lose `text-align: center` when you do this.

Answer (score 5):

Here' the crack. I  was looking for an answer (`vertical-align`) not it's alternate (`bottom: 0`). So here's the solution.

`vertical-align` is set with respect to its container, not the parent (or `wrapper`) element. So just give some line-height to it and then apply the  `vertical-align: bottom`.

```css
    div {
        background:yellow;
        margin:10px;
        line-height:100px;
    }
    div > * {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        line-height: normal;
    }

    a {
        background-color:#FFF;
        height:20px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:solid black 1px;
        padding:5px;
    }

    span {
        background:red;
        width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
    <a>Some link</a>
    <span>Some text </span>
    </div>
```